# Does $\,f_* \mathcal{O}_{X_T} \cong \mathcal{O}_{T}$ hold in this situation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a scheme over $S$ and consider the following hypothesis :
\begin{cases}
\; (1) \quad f:X\to S \text{ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated } \\\\
\; (2) \quad f:X\to S \text{ admits a section } \varepsilon:S\to X \\\\   
\; (3) \quad f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T} \cong \mathcal{O}_T \text{ for every $S$-scheme } T \\   
\end{cases}

where $X_T$ is the fiber product between $X$ and an $S$-scheme $T$, and by an abuse of notation we denote by $\,f$ the pullback morphism, as well.

Now assume $X$ is a smooth projective curve over $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$, with $k$ an algebraically closed field. In this situation the first two of the above hypothesis are fulfilled, since:

1. $X$ projective implies $\,f$ quasi-compact, while $X$ curve (hence Noetherian) implies $\,f$ quasi-separated
2. $k$ is algebraically closed $X$ admits a rational point, hence a section exists (sending $S$ to the point)

Do you agree with the above reasoning?

And what about $(3)$? Is this also automatically fulfilled in this situation, or shall I require it separately?

Comment: projective => separated => quasi-separated holds in general.

Comment: I think that 3) holds when $f$ has geometrically integral fibers, so yes, here this holds.

Comment: Hi Martin, as always thanks for your comments! Could you please give the sketch of an argument or a reference for your claim "integral fibers $\implies (3)$" ?

Answer (score 1):

For $T$ noetherian, you can prove it by showing that $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T}\otimes k(t)\rightarrow H^0(X_t, \mathcal{O}_{X_t})$ is surjective: since $H^0(X_t, \mathcal{O}_{X_t})\cong H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})\otimes k(t)\cong k(t)$, hence $\mathcal{O}_T\otimes k(t)\cong H^0(X_t, \mathcal{O}_{X_t})$, so $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T}\otimes k(t)\rightarrow H^0(X_t, \mathcal{O}_{X_t})$ is surjective. Then Hartshorne III.12.11 implies $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T}$ is a locally free sheaf on $T$ whose rank is equal to $\dim_{k(t)}H^0(X_t, \mathcal{O}_{X_t})=1$, hence $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T}=\mathcal{O}_T$. In fact, we only use the fact that $X$ is an integral projective scheme over $k=\bar{k}$.